# Command-arrow for back and forward one word in PhpStorm terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, phpstorm, command-line-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm on OSX, and for some reason, when I do command - ← (back arrow) in the PhpStorm terminal I get a `[D`, while command - → (forward arrow) outputs a `[C`. What I want to do is jump forward and back one word.

[image]

In my OSX terminal these keypresses work as expected, and I can't find anywhere where they are set to output those characters. Does anyone have the answer to this conundrum?

Comment: Alt + →/← works fine for me in the both system and PhpStorm terminal, and, basically, everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, must be a mapping I put in myself somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that an answer for the same problem on iTerm also works for PhpStorm! The fix involves creating a new file named `~/.inputrc` and then put the following code in it:

```
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
```

Here is the original [link](https://www.petercarrero.com/content/2016/09/23/make-word-back-and-word-forwards-navigation-work-again-phpstorms-terminal)

Comment: Joy!! Thanks Alexander, a solution at last! (Note for others - you have to restart PhpStorm.)

Comment: Can I fix this on Windows 10 aswell?

Comment: Worked for me with RubyMine on macOS

Answer (score 2):

If you are using zsh, add this to **~/.zshrc**:

```
bindkey "\e\eOD" backward-word
bindkey "\e\eOC" forward-word
```